# Enumerating through Yahoo Pipes generated JSON with jQuery fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to lessen manual update work by using Yahoo Pipes and jQuery to update a table with upcoming events from a different domain. I have created [this Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=57aa32bf3481c8dca0c07afcf9b9dc29) to gather the data, and it *seems* to work.

Now I am reading the JSON file with the following jQuery Script taken from [this tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/):

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=57aa32bf3481c8dca0c07afcf9b9dc29&_render=json",
 async: false,
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  $('body').append(data.query.results.a.content);
 }
});
```

The jQuery append failes, I guess because 'data.query.results.a.content' does not relate well to the JSON structure created by the pipe.

I've tried altering both the pipe and the append in several ways and am just short of giving up, I'd be very grateful for your Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are parsing the json result incorrectly.

On viewing the json object here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

You will observe **content** node for each **item** is at  `value.items[0].a.content`

i.e. try something like this :

```
$('body').append(data.value.items[0].a.content);
```

You will need to iterate the items array like this

```
$.each(data.value.items, function(index,element) {
    $('body').append(element.a.content);
});
```

Try it on fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/EFvJf/

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Also, thanks for pointing me to jsonviewer and jsfiddle, I think that's going to help tremendeously.

Comment: glad to help :) also use make use of firebug and chrome developer tools ..those are great for web development http://getfirebug.com/ and https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ .. IE has developer toolbar too.. also see questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203991/what-tool-to-use-for-javascript-development

Comment: Little update: got it working just as intended, thanks again!